# Stay in previous state unless button pressed

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, arduino

I have simple code Here. I am calling two function display lcd and check key. by default screen should display date and time. if up arrow pressed go to particular window and show date and  time. similarly down key pressed. display menu should decremented.

Problem:Date and time Displaying properly . once up key pressed menu being changed, But as soon as enter menu directly jumping back to date and time..
**Declaration of enum values:**

```
typedef enum {
  DATE_TIME,
  COORDINATE,
  WINDSPEED,
  POSITIONTRACK,
  DISPAY_PARAMETER,
  SET_PARAMETER,
  DISPLAY_TYPE_MAX
}
DISPLAY_SCREEN_TYPE;
//DISPLAY_SCREEN_TYPE display_screen_type=DATE_TIME;
```

**Declaration of button functions**

```
#define btnRIGHT  0     // Okay
#define btnUP     1     // inc
#define btnDOWN   2     // dec
#define btnLEFT   3     // Select
#define btnSELECT 4     // Menu
#define btnNONE   5
```

Functionality:

```
void loop()
{ 
  Display_LCD();
  Chk_key(); 
}
void Display_LCD()
{
  switch(display_screen_type)
  {
  case DATE_TIME:
    digitalClockDisplay(); 
    break;     
  case COORDINATE:
    Display_coordinate(); 
    break; 
  case WINDSPEED:
    Display_Wind();
    break;
  case POSITIONTRACK:
    Display_angle();
    break;  
  case DISPAY_PARAMETER:
    Display_fun();
    break;
  case SET_PARAMETER:
    Set_Fun(); 
    break;
  case DISPLAY_TYPE_MAX:
    break;    
  }
  if(display_screen_type>DISPLAY_TYPE_MAX)
  {
    display_screen_type=DATE_TIME;
  }
}
void Chk_key()
{
  int button=read_LCD_buttons();
  switch(button)
  {
  case btnRIGHT:
    Action_RIGHT();
    break;
  case btnUP:
    Action_UP();
    break;    
  case btnDOWN:
    Action_DOWN();
    break;  
  case btnLEFT: 
    Action_LEFT();
    break;
  case btnSELECT:
    Action_SELECT(); 
    break; 
  } 
}

void Action_UP()
{   
  switch(display_screen_type)
  {
  case DATE_TIME: 
    display_screen_type= COORDINATE; 
    Update_Display=1;
    break;   
  case COORDINATE: 
    display_screen_type= WINDSPEED; 
    Update_Display=1;
    break;    
  case WINDSPEED:  
    display_screen_type= POSITIONTRACK; 
    Update_Display=1;
    break;        
  case POSITIONTRACK:
    display_screen_type= DATE_TIME; 
    Update_Display=1;
    break; 
    //default:display_screen_type= DATE_TIME; Update_Display=1;delay(500);break; 
  }  

}

void Action_DOWN()
{
  /* lcdClear(); 
    lcd.print("DOWN");*/

  switch(display_screen_type)
  {
  case DATE_TIME: 
    display_screen_type= POSITIONTRACK; 
    Update_Display=1;
    break;   
  case COORDINATE: 
    display_screen_type= DATE_TIME; 
    Update_Display=1;
    break;    
  case WINDSPEED:  
    display_screen_type= COORDINATE; 
    Update_Display=1;
    break;        
  case POSITIONTRACK:
    display_screen_type= WINDSPEED; 
    Update_Display=1;
    break; 
    //default:display_screen_type= DATE_TIME; Update_Display=1;break; 
  }  
}
```

Modified code is here:

```
int display_screen_type=DATE_TIME; 


void loop()
{
  Display_LCD();
  Chk_key(); 
}

void Display_LCD()
{
  switch(display_screen_type)
  {

  case DATE_TIME: 
    digitalClockDisplay(); 
    timedBeep(beep,1); 
    break;  
  case COORDINATE: 
    Display_coordinate();
    timedBeep(beep,1); 
    break;     
  case WINDSPEED:
    Display_Wind();
    timedBeep(beep,1); 
    break;  
  case POSITIONTRACK:  
    Display_angle(); 
    timedBeep(beep,1); 
    break;    
  case DISPAY_PARAMETER: 
    Display_fun();
    timedBeep(beep,1); 
    break; 
  case SET_PARAMETER:
    Set_Fun(); 
    timedBeep(beep,1);
    break;
  case GET_PASSWORD:
    Get_Password();
    timedBeep(beep,1);
    break;
  }
}

void Action_UP()
{  

  if(display_screen_type >=POSITIONTRACK)
    display_screen_type=DATE_TIME;
  else
    display_screen_type++; 
}

void Action_DOWN()
{
  if(display_screen_type <=DATE_TIME)
    display_screen_type=POSITIONTRACK;
  else
    display_screen_type--; 
}


void Chk_key()
{
  int button=read_LCD_buttons();
  if(button!=prev_button) 
  {
    prev_button = button; 
  }

  switch(prev_button)
  {
  case btnRIGHT:// RIGHT/MENU BUTTON BEING SELECTED
    Action_RIGHT();
    break;
  case btnUP:// UP KEY/INCREMENT PRESSED   
    Action_UP();  
    break;
  case btnDOWN: // DOWN / DECREMENT KEY  PRESSED 
    Action_DOWN();
    break;
  case btnLEFT://LEFT / ESCAPE KEY PRESSED
    Action_LEFT();
    break;
  case btnSELECT://SELECT KEY PRESSED
    Action_SELECT(); 
    break;   
  } 
}
```

Comment: `Update_Display` variable like not seen here where it will use after it set to 1.Also not require `switch_case` for down and up event.

Comment: initially used it , but i removed. i have kept counter inside the display lcd function if counter reached 5 update value and else dont update screen. but i found that my Date and time not displaying. displaying only when counter reaches value 5. So i by passed it. when up arrow being pressed increment display_screen_type /down key pressed decrements  display_screen_type

Comment: Also where you set `display_screen_type` to `DISPLAY_TYPE_MAX`? or increment the `display_screen_type`?

Comment: here whenever key being pressed it look previous **display_screen_type** .initially it display default  **display_screen_type** as date-time . when key pressed it check previously under DATE_TIME for next it will update to next display COORDINATE. but here instead of staying COORDINATE: it goes back to DATE_TIME

Comment: **Problem:Date and time Displaying properly . once up key pressed menu being changed, But as soon as enter menu directly jumping back to date and time.i wanted to stay in menu ITSELF UNLESS OTHER KEY BEING PRESSED.**

Comment: look my updated answer and make changes as per it.

Comment: I have done this . but it remaining two state DATE_TIME & COORDINATE. the code i pasted making increment and decrements of menu works fine but not staying particular menu itself.

Comment: ok, can you post updated source?

Comment: Code i have Written where it describe , what is function of right Key under particular display.**Whatever change you told working fine now stay particular window .i.e what expected** The action function created because.Assume in set parameter where i declare the function of up key. means  if i want to increment value i choose up key to increment so how can use action key to define

Comment: So `Chk_key` is function for getting key event right?And also please post your modified code with my changes to question window.So i can get batter idea where is wrong. And `loop` function is continuously called? from where it called?

Comment: Yes check key is to check event key :Whenever key pressed some action will be taken @ particular display screen.**loop** is like main function in c. Assume i am set parameter. when Up key being pressed In action of  set_parameter window is too increment the values for example date in format dd/mm/yy and down to decrements left to switch from dd to mm  and select key to save result

Answer (score 0):

your code seems require lot of improvement first it why you compare `display_screen_type` in 
`Display_LCD` function?
Just leave it for only display and manage it in `Action_UP` or `Action_DOWN`

For increment/decrements `display_screen_type` you must take it as type `int`

```
int display_screen_type=DATE_TIME;
```

your `Action_UP` and `Action_DOWN` should be like this

```
void Action_UP()
{   
    if(display_screen_type >=DISPLAY_TYPE_MAX)
        display_screen_type=DATE_TIME
    else
        display_screen_type++; 
}

void Action_DOWN()
{    
    if(display_screen_type <= DATE_TIME)
        display_screen_type=SET_PARAMETER
    else
        display_screen_type--; 
}
```

Also below condition not require in `Display_LCD` so remove it.

```
  if(display_screen_type>DISPLAY_TYPE_MAX)
  {
    display_screen_type=DATE_TIME;
  }
```

Comment: but they are **enum** values. you can increment enum values. so it gives out the error   no 'operator++(int)' declared for postfix '++', trying prefix operator instead

Comment: `DISPLAY_SCREEN_TYPE` is your enum and it's not necessary that you can take `display_screen_type`  as enum but you can take as `int` or try it with `--display_screen_type` and `++display_screen_type`

Comment: i tried with this it giving error **no match for 'operator++' in '++display_screen_type'**  above case  i changed **display_screen_type++** to **++display_screen_type**

Comment: An `enum` is a list of enumerated integer values. It is not an array. Hence, there is no ++ operator defined for moving through the list of values.So declared `int display_screen_type=DATE_TIME` instead `DISPLAY_SCREEN_TYPE display_screen_type=DATE_TIME;`

Comment: but it is not staying previous state of button being pressed . going directly back to **display_screen_type=DATE_TIME;**

Comment: @user3378973 have modified your code as per my suggestion? if yes then post your updated code in question  window.